# How do i filter the processed files by a front-matter variable (Eleventy / 11ty)?

Tags: eleventy

Actually, i want to prevent all content files (in our case markdown files) with a `version` set to `draft` to be processed by eleventy (so not rendered / copied to the output directory).

Comment: Do the files have a value for permalink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking an example from this blog post (https://rusingh.com/2020/05/14/eleventy-exclude-draft-collection-items-programmatically/), you can use a directory data file that examines the front matter and when `drafts === 'version'`, returns false for permalink. This worked for me:

```js
module.exports = {

    eleventyComputed: {
        permalink: (data) => {
            if(data.version && data.version === 'draft') return false;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The referenced article is great! This trick does not work completely for me, because the file with `version: draft` is indeed not published, but is still in the collection (so still shows up in the menu). But this is easy to fix.

Comment: Don't forget you can make a new collection based on another collection. That's what I'd do.